# Solve $ a!b!=a!+b!+c! $

Tags: number-theory

After solving the equation $ abc=a!+b!+c!     $ in natural numbers which yield $a=1,b=2, c=3$ i tried to attempt the above question given in title. However i am not getting any clue. As far i think, may be some logical reasoning will be required just like one attempts to solve problems like $AA+BB=AB$ etc.

But here in this question how shall i proceed to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where did you get this, exactly?

Comment: For your solution to the first equation, $abc = a! + b! +c!$, the left hand side gives 6 and the right hand side 9.

Comment: @Bennett Oh God! My mistake, thank you for alerting me. Now I have to think on it again separately. But thank you again.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon wow! Yes, it certainly did. I never realized i was attempting such olympiad question. Many many thanks a lot for such a great help.

Comment: @Anjan3 Presh Talwalkar has got a video on this problem on YouTube, his videos may be illustrative for you. He does many of these videos for olympiad and other challenging questions as well. He has written good books as well, so you would do well to take a look at his material.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon yes i heard his name and i used to check his youtube videoa as well for his excellent explanation. Would you mind to share the direct link of the video in which he solve this current problem plz ?

Comment: Never mind. I have found it .. Thank you

Comment: @Anjan3 You are welcome!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon part way along programming Miller-Rabin for the $1 + 2020^n$  problem. Not correct yet, but it is clearly the way to go.

Comment: @WillJagy Looking forward to the results!